# proving a theorem in Coq

Tags: coq, theorem

I am trying to prove a theorem in Coq and I am not able to solve an issue that occurs. I am trying to solve:

```
 forall A B C: Prop, A\/(B\/C)->(A\/B)\/C.
Proof.
intros.
destruct H as [H1 | [H2 | H3 ]].
Case H1.
and in this last line I get the following error "Error: The reference Case was not found in the current environment."
```

I am new to Coq so I do not know what that really means. I did some research on the Internet but I did not manage to find a solution. Does anyone have an idea of what this problem comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've destructed the hypothesis, so you're already analyzing each case.

Use `left` and `right` to manipulate the disjunction in the conclusion, and `assumption` when a hypothesis and the conclusion are the same.

Comment: yes, but why do I have this error for "Case H1"? What sould I do in order to fix it?

Comment: What were you trying to do with that? "Case" does not exist in Coq, were you trying to use "case"?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Hmm... I might have misunderstood what you were trying to do here actually...

---

The `Case` that you are using and have probably seen used elsewhere is not built in Coq, but rather is a library that has been floating around in the Coq ecosystem.

I can find a reference to it here: http://coq.inria.fr/cocorico/Case%20(tactic)

I have also used it personally. To use it, you need to either copy the definition in that link somewhere in your file, or in another file `MyCaseModule.v` that you import then:

```
Require Import MyCaseModule.
```

---

As a side-note, Coq 8.4 seems to offer another way to structure proofs using bullets. I do not know exactly the details, as I am stuck using 8.3 for other reasons. However, you might still prefer Case/SCase/... for its ability to give names to the different cases.